# recharts horizontal lines from horizontalPoints are bunched together

Tags: recharts

im trying to create a graph in recharts with cartesian grid and horizontal lines.
but then im using horizontalPoints  property , the horizontal lines are all bunched together instead of spread like theu should.

any idea why ?

my code:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width={width} height={height} className={styles.graph}>
<ComposedChart margin={{ top: 20, right: 25, left: 25, bottom: 20 }}  height="100%">
<XAxis ... />
<YAxis ... />
<CartesianGrid class={styles.horizontal} horizontal={true} vertical={false} horizontalPoints={[15, 30, 45, 60]}
</ComposedChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this might be a bit late,

but the values for the grid lines of the CartesianGrid that recharts accepts are not values that relate to the corresponding axis but rather pixel-offsets from the top/right side of the chart.

So a CartesianGrid with horizontal lines at `[0, 100, 200]` would draw three grid lines. The first at the top of the chart. The second 100px below the top of the chart and the third 200px below the top.

I hope this helps!